# VB.net listview checkbox get selected item

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with ListView. How to set a listView to selected when I click it?

**My code:**

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.listAwal.Items 
    item.Selected = True
Next
```

I use this but items on listview are all selected if I select one item.

Comment: Selecteditems and CheckedItems are 2 different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to get the checked property but are instead setting the selected property. Try this:

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.listAwal.Items 
    If item.Checked Then
        'Do something with this item
    End If
Next
```

Comment: As Plutonix said, checked and selected are not the same thing. An item can be selected but not checked and vice versa. Maybe we are misunderstanding your question due to a language barrier? Could you try to clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: `For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.listAwal.Items
            If item.Checked = True Then
                item.Selected = True
            ElseIf item.Checked = False Then
                item.Selected = False
            End If
            'PR
        Next`

Comment: now , i have one problem , if I uncheck the item , checkbox on listview uncheck all

Comment: That shouldn't happen with the code you posted. Has it changed? What event handler are you writing this in?

Comment: listview_ item checked

Comment: it can , but i uncheck one checkbox on listview , other checkbox become uncheck

Comment: Do you also have a sub written for _SelectedIndexChanged? All the code in your comment does is select checked items and unselect unchecked items. If _SelectedIndexChanged unchecks everything, that would explain your issue.